# SQL Trigger doesn't get fired

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

So I have to make an import for a CSV file in ASP.NET, and after that is need to be sorted in the right tables.

The importing works and I use a trigger to furthe sort out the data, but when I run the code it doesn't get fired. I kind of new to SQL so please be gentle :)
Here is my code:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER sortTables
    ON CSVtussenTabel
    AFTER INSERT
    AS
    declare @titel varchar(100);
    declare @artiest varchar(100);
    declare @jaar int;
    declare @positie int;
    declare @eindzenddatum datetime;
    declare @van float;
    declare @tot float;

    declare @artiestTeller int;
    declare @songTeller int;

    set @titel = (SELECT Titel FROM CSVtussenTabel);
    set @artiest = (SELECT Artiest FROM CSVtussenTabel);
    set @jaar = (SELECT Jaar FROM CSVtussenTabel);
    set @positie = (SELECT Positie FROM CSVtussenTabel);
    set @eindzenddatum = (SELECT Eindzenddatum FROM CSVtussenTabel);
    set @van = (SELECT Van FROM CSVtussenTabel);
    set @tot = (SELECT Tot FROM CSVtussenTabel);

    set @artiestTeller = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Artiest) + 1;
    set @songTeller = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Song) + 1;
    IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Artiest WHERE @artiest IN (SELECT naam FROM         Artiest)) = 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Artiest (naam)VALUES ( @artiest);
    END

    IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Song WHERE @titel IN (SELECT titel FROM Song)) = 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Song (songid, artiestid, titel, jaar) VALUES (@songTeller, @artiestTeller, @titel, @jaar);
    END

    IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Lijst WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, @eindzenddatum) IN (SELECT top2000jaar FROM Lijst)) = 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Lijst (songid, top2000jaar, positie, uitzenddatum, van, tot)VALUES (@songteller, DATEPART(YEAR, @eindzenddatum), @positie, @eindzenddatum, @van, @tot);
    END
    GO
```

Comment: Which dbms? (Doesn't look like ANSI SQL...)

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: There is an `inserted` pseudo-table that contains the rows affected by the `INSERT` statement. You're just selecting random data from the table with your `set @titel = (SELECT Titel FROM CSVtussenTabel);` style queries. Even if you changed them to use `inserted` instead, your trigger would still be broken - because note that I said *rows*, not *row*. Triggers need to be written to deal with the entire *set* of rows that have been inserted.

Comment: I didn't even know where to start explaining what is wrong with this script :). Variables are incorrect, approach is incorrect and those if statements - they are also incorrect. I can only suggest that OP should learn more about SQL and MSSQL first.

Comment: @GrzegorzW I know, it's for a school project. And as I said I'm new to SQL (should have left 'kinda' out), that's why I turned to Stackoverflow with the hope that someone could atleast give me some advice, and this already helped me out. So thanks :)